# Eclipse RCP E4 Part Stack Width not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have one perspective in which there are two Part Stack.
By default each Part Stack occupies half of the window , I want to set fist part stack width as 30% and second one as 70%.

I have tried setting Container data as 30 for PartStak1 and 70 for PartStack2 but it's not working,

Plaese help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a `PartSashContainer` as the parent of the two `PartStack`s for this to work.